# What is the lifetime kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The following code are from the project architecture samples at https://github.com/android/architecture-samples

What is the lifetime `kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope` in Kotlin? Will this function `saveTask` return as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed?

If I pass a `ViewModel.viewModelScope` to `DefaultTasksRepository` instead of `kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope`, what are differents ?

BTW, it seems that the Code A don't pass any object of CoroutineScope, why?

**Code A**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
...

class DefaultTasksRepository(
    private val tasksRemoteDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val tasksLocalDataSource: TasksDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : TasksRepository {

   ...
   override suspend fun saveTask(task: Task) {
        coroutineScope {
            launch { tasksRemoteDataSource.saveTask(task) }
            launch { tasksLocalDataSource.saveTask(task) }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
object ServiceLocator {

    private val lock = Any()
    private var database: ToDoDatabase? = null

    ...

    private fun createTasksRepository(context: Context): TasksRepository {
        val newRepo = DefaultTasksRepository(FakeTasksRemoteDataSource, createTaskLocalDataSource(context))
        tasksRepository = newRepo
        return newRepo
    }

   ...
}
```

**Added content**

To Animesh Sahu: Thanks!

Are you sure that *"A coroutineScope is a factory function that creates a CoroutineScope"* , the following code is source code, it seems that the return value is not the object of `CoroutineScope`.

**Source Code**

```
  public suspend fun <R> coroutineScope(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> R): R =
    suspendCoroutineUninterceptedOrReturn { uCont ->
        val coroutine = ScopeCoroutine(uCont.context, uCont)
        coroutine.startUndispatchedOrReturn(coroutine, block)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [coroutineScope](http://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) is a factory function that creates a [CoroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-scope/) with the same context as it was called with but overriding the Job of that context.

`CoroutineScope` has lifetime until it is cancelled by calling `cancel()` on it or calling `cancel()` on `CoroutineScope.coroutineContext` or explicitly calling on the attached job `coroutineContext[Job].cancel()`.

a `coroutineScope` is just a wrapper that creates immediate `CoroutineScope` that cancels itself up after executing its childrens.

**PS: coroutineScope function is used for parallel decomposition of tasks with a new Job instance for control over its children**

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW it does not returns it, it pass it as a receiver into the lambda.